# Jmeter not able to overcome dynamically keep on adding parameters in the requested page

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

One banking page whose request body(data, images, JSON parameters)frequently changing.So existing script in jmeter got failed.How to track these and put it in script & successfully run by jmeter.
OR Do I need to record the script again and again??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you don't have to record it again and again. 
You can capture the requests with fiddler or any other traffic capturing tool and compare it to your Jmeter requests, then edit your request's parameters according to the changes you got by comparing requests from your script and fiddler capture.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.My query is if user keep on adding the data(next suppose 500 new rows) under the same page which I recorded before, will this fiddler take up those newly created request? So every time through fiddler only need to check , compare and run the script?.Is there any other way which can give notification for the changes?@ararar

Comment: Can you please explain more about this page, like how the data is being added, how often, also is your jmeter script dynamic?. And fiddler can show you all the http/s requests data, [for more information about fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/web-app-performance-testing)

Comment: This page is actually dynamic page where user information adding every time like 1 st time may be bank a/c is added along with all the info. Next time, may be couple of weeks, another set of info gets updated in the same page like (SSL,PAN,etc.banking info) So every time set of records gets updated.In this case my previous recorded scripts got failed due to changes.Page urls and section names are same.only request body are changing.So in this case,only fiddler can help me out to check for changes in request body which is time consuming too? or is there any other way work around?-----@ ararar

Comment: Jmeter script is dynamic and this page is getting change weekly

Comment: Actually i don't know of any other way, but if its only one request that changes which is the one for this page, i don't think it would take much time to fix your request's body according to the changes.